# Convert json object in to array to iterate through ng-repeat using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

Here is my sample json , i am getting my json obj from firebase i have to convert the list in to array to bind in html trough ng-repeat.

### my Json object is

```
  {
  "cats1": {
    "Name": "cricket",
    "imgUrl": "some url",
    "list1": {
      "bat": {
        "Name": "bat",
        "imgUrl": "some url",
        "price": "$100"
      },
      "pads": {
        "displayName": "pads",
        "imgUrl": "some url",
        "price": "$50"
      }
    }
  },
  "cats2": {
    "Name": "football",
    "imgUrl": "some url"
  }
}
```

### this is how i required

this is the array structure i required , when i add the new list it must store uniquely in cricket category.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "cricket",
    "imgUrl": "some url",
    "list1": [
      {
        "Name": "bat",
        "imgUrl": "some url",
        "price": "$100"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "pads",
        "imgUrl": "some url",
        "price": "$50"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "football",
    "imgUrl": "some url"
  }
]
```

i am new to angular any one please help me to figure out this problem

Comment: `Object.keys(data).map(x=>data[x])`

Comment: @Rajesh Op doesn't want 'bat'

Comment: @Mahi he does. He just wants list to be array as well

Comment: @Rajesh look at the required output then

Comment: can any one explain me using for loops

Comment: @Rajesh he need array of object not cascaded object

Comment: sorry nested object

Comment: @Mahi Apologies for my misunderstanding. I have added an answer. Hope it serve the purpose. Please let me know if anything needs changing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `Object.keys` and pass them on to `Array.prototype.map` to create the array that you want - see demo below:

```js
var object={cats1:{Name:"cricket",imgUrl:"some url",list1:{bat:{Name:"bat",imgUrl:"some url",price:"$100"},pads:{displayName:"pads",imgUrl:"some url",price:"$50"}}},cats2:{Name:"football",imgUrl:"some url"}};

var result = Object.keys(object).map(e=>object[e]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

**EDIT**:

Correcting the solution to make `list1` an array:

```js
var object={cats1:{Name:"cricket",imgUrl:"some url",list1:{bat:{Name:"bat",imgUrl:"some url",price:"$100"},pads:{displayName:"pads",imgUrl:"some url",price:"$50"}}},cats2:{Name:"football",imgUrl:"some url"}};

var result = Object.keys(object).map(function(e){
  Object.keys(object[e]).forEach(function(k){
     if(typeof object[e][k] == "object") {
       object[e][k] = Object.keys(object[e][k]).map(function(l){
         return object[e][k][l];
       });
     }
  });
  return object[e];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: Op doesn't want `bat` ??

Comment: should i revert upvote than ?

Comment: nice one :) ...

Comment: how do i check if properties has object ??

Comment: so it wont work if op has one more nested object :P

Comment: This will restrict to just 1 level down. I'd rather suggest using recursion.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can recursion but do note this can cause freeze for big objects and can also lead to `Maximum Call Stack exceeded`

#### Logic

- Loop over object and check if all entries are objects.
- If yes, then a simple `Object.keys(obj).map(x=>obj[x])` will do.
- If not, then you will have to copy individual values and if object, then again loop in it for inner objects. A simple way is to loop on every key and if type is not object, just return value.

```js
function ObjectToArray(obj) {
  if (typeof(obj) === 'object') {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var allObjects = keys.every(x => typeof(obj[x]) === 'object');
    if (allObjects) {
      return keys.map(x => ObjectToArray(obj[x]));
    } else {
      var o = {};
      keys.forEach(x => {
        o[x] = ObjectToArray(obj[x])
      });
      return o;
    }
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}

var d={cats1:{Name:"cricket",imgUrl:"some url",list1:{bat:{Name:"bat",imgUrl:"some url",price:"$100"},pads:{displayName:"pads",imgUrl:"some url",price:"$50"}}},cats2:{Name:"football",imgUrl:"some url"}};

console.log(ObjectToArray(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, by iterating over the input object keys and stripping out the keys.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.result = {
      "cats1": {
        "Name": "cricket",
        "imgUrl": "some url",
        "list1": {
          "bat": {
            "Name": "bat",
            "imgUrl": "some url",
            "price": "$100"
          },
          "pads": {
            "displayName": "pads",
            "imgUrl": "some url",
            "price": "$50"
          }
        }
      },
      "cats2": {
        "Name": "football",
        "imgUrl": "some url"
      }
    };
    $scope.format = Object.keys($scope.result).map((key) => $scope.result[key])
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">

    <div>Formatted</div>
    <pre>{{format | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: op doesn't want `bat`

Comment: aah.. overlooked. thanks for pointing it out